# Updating changes rows

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a requirement to update a couple of thousand rows in a table based on whether any changes have happened to any of the values.  At the moment I'm just updating all the values regardless but was wondering what was more efficient.  Should I check all the columns to see if there are any changes and update or should I just update regardless? e.g

```
 update someTable Set
   column1 = somevalue,
   column2 = somevalue,
   column3 = somevalue,
   etc....
 from someTable inner join sometable2 on
   someTable.id = sometable2.id
 where 
   someTable.column1 != sometable2.column1 or
   someTable.column2 != sometable2.column2 or
   someTable.column2 != sometable2.column2 or
   etc etc......
```

What's faster and what's best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is the best way.

Tables and data:

```
declare @someTable1 table(id int, column1 int, column2 varchar(2))
declare @someTable2 table(id int, column1 int, column2 varchar(2))

insert @someTable1 
          select 1,10 a, 'a3'
union all select 2,20  , 'a3' 
union all select 3,null, 'a4'

insert @someTable2
          select 1,10,   'a3' 
union all select 2,19,   'a3' 
union all select 3,null, 'a5'
```

Update:

```
UPDATE t1
set t1.column1 = t2.column1,
t1.column2 = t2.column2
from @someTable1 t1
JOIN 
(select * from @someTable2
EXCEPT
select * from @someTable1) t2
on t2.id = t1.id
```

Result:

```
select * from @someTable1

id          a        b
----------- -------- --
1           10       a3
2           19       a3
3           NULL     a5
```

Answer (score 1):

See two articles on Paul White's Blog.

1. [The Impact of Non-Updating Updates](http://web.archive.org/web/20180406220621/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/08/11/the_2D00_impact_2D00_of_2D00_update_2D00_statements_2D00_that_2D00_don_2D00_t_2D00_change_2D00_data.aspx) for discussion of the main issue.
2. [Undocumented Query Plans: Equality Comparisons](http://web.archive.org/web/20180422151947/http://sqlblog.com:80/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/06/22/undocumented-query-plans-equality-comparisons.aspx) for a less tedious way of doing the inequality comparisons particularly if your columns are nullable (`WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT someTable.* INTERSECT SELECT someTable2.*)`).

Answer (score 0):

I've found that explicitly including the where clause the excludes no-op updates to perform faster, when working against large tables, but this is a very YMMV type of question.

If possible, compare the two approaches side by side, against a realistic set of data. E.g. if your tables contain millions of rows, and the updates affect only 10, make sure your sample data affects just a few rows. Or likewise, if it's likely that most rows will change, make your sample data reflect that.